# Constructing functions with variable number of output arguments

Tags: function-construction

In Mathematica, you can construct a function `f` to have different definitions based on its input arguments. For example, `f[x_] := ...` and `f[x_, y_] := ...`. You can also get more specific and define it for specific heads as `f[x_someHead] := ...` or inputs matching arbitrary patterns as `f[x_?somePatternQ] := ...` (of course, one must be careful to keep the order from specific to general). These definitions are the `DownValues` of the function.

Now, I'd like to construct a function that has different definitions based on *the number of output variables/symbols requested*, but for the same set of inputs. Consider the following dummy example in pseudo Mathematica code

```
f[mu_, sigma2_] := Switch[OutputArgs[], 
                           0, Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[mu, sigma2], x], ...]
                           1, RandomReal[NormalDistribution[mu, sigma2], 1000]
                           2, {Mean@#, Variance@#}&@ RandomReal[...]
                   ]
```

Here `OutputArgs[]` is a functionality that I'd like, which when called from inside a function, tells you how many outputs have been *requested* (loosely reminiscent of `OptionValue` which knows which function it's called from). With this, I can use the function call simply as `f[0,1]` to plot the normal distribution (perhaps inside a `Manipulate` to play with the parameters), then when I'm satisfied, I can use the same function call, but with an output argument as `a = f[0,1]` to get a random sample, and with two outputs to get an empirical estimate of the mean and variance.

I realize that this is a bit at odds with the classical notion of a function having a well defined output based on the input, rather than a well defined output based on the number of outputs for a given input.

---

My interest is purely academic and arose from working on porting some MATLAB code to Mathematica. Some might have recognized that right away, and this is a feature that that I *do* find useful — a sentiment also shared by a few others that I've spoken to here. I wouldn't write code this way and I know that it is also possible to achieve the same by other means such as using flags as `f[0, 1, "Plot"]` or options as `f[0, 1, Options -> "RandomSample"]`, etc. for the above example. However, I'm interested in exploring if there are ways to imitate this behaviour in Mathematica.

Comment: What about making OuptutArgs an option? Something link f[mu_, sigma2_,OptionsPattern[]] := Switch[
                      OptionsValue[OutputArgs], 
                           0, Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[mu, sigma2], x], ...],
                           1, RandomReal[NormalDistribution[mu, sigma2], 1000],
                           2, {Mean@#, Variance@#}&@ RandomReal[...]
                   ]

Comment: Sorry, you do not want any options (and I seem not to be able to delete my above comment after 5 minutes. weird). But then how does it work in MATLAB? I.e., how is the "requesting" done?

Comment: What's wrong with doing it in the way you indicate above? Obviously you'd have to define OutputArgs[], but that's unavoidable. Mind you, I'm not sure I see an advantage over options or optional arguments.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I guess the question then is, how does one define `OutputArgs[]`? I don't know how to "know" from within the function how many outputs are requested. As for advantages, I don't think there are any, and if I write a function, I probably would do it with options. This thought occurred when I tried to port a script to mma, and I was puzzling over how one would go about doing it, if so desired.

Comment: @RolfMertig I don't know how the requesting is done in MATLAB under the hood. In the code, you can use [`nargout`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/nargout.html) inside the body of the function, and it returns the number of output arguments used in the call. Re: the comments, you should be able to delete, but not edit after 5 mins. If you hover over it, next to `X mins ago`, you should see an `x` mark.

Comment: Okay, now I'm confused. Some code somewhere needs to have a notion of what it wants. Or perhaps the user knows, and OutputArgs[] could request Input[]. If it is the caller, I don't see much point to NOT passing that information. But I guess it could use a variable "outputSize", and maybe OutputArgs[] would query that variable. There are various tactics for avoiding use of a global variable. But again, all this seems like a lot of trouble for the desired result.

Comment: It's likely that whatever MATLAB does under the hood, it basically comes down to passing an extra parameter representing `nargout`.

Comment: I realized it was from MATLAB, but I think many people will be very confused by the question and won't get your point.  Why don't you show a small MATLAB example, just to clarify?  Examples always make things so much more clear.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As you have mentioned there are other more standard ways to provide some variaty in your return value so I don't think that this is something that you should do. If you provide code using something like it you should have good reasons for doing so. Just being used to it because matlab has it probably is just not convincing enough.

That said, it can be done along these lines:

```
ClearAll[f, ff]
f /: Set[arg_Symbol, f[x_]] := Block[{nargout = 1}, arg = ff[x]];
f /: Set[args_List, f[x_]] := Block[{nargout = Length[args]}, args = ff[x]];
f[arg_] /; FreeQ[Stack[], Set] := Block[{nargout = 1}, ff[arg]];
ff[x_] := (Table[x, {nargout}]);
```

you can now use it like this:

```
In[101]:= f[5]
Out[101]= {5}
In[102]:= a=f[5]
Out[102]= {5}
In[104]:= {a,b}=f[5]
Out[104]= {5,5}
In[105]:= {a,b,c}=f[5]
Out[105]= {5,5,5}
```

This is not tested well and could have many pitfalls. I see it rather as a proof of concept and probably something for your own convenience. So use with care, especially if you are uncertain about all the details (as I am: I can't remember I ever had the need to use `Stack`).

Brett already found one pitfall. Actually that is a case where one could be argueing what the expected return value should be. If we fall back to the one argument case for everything that is not an explicit Set it is easy to solve, but I can see other problems already :-):

```
f[arg_] /; Not[MatchQ[Stack[],{___,Set,f,___}]]:=Block[{nargout=1},ff[arg]];
```

Comment: +1 for `FreeQ[Stack[], Set]`, I was trying to work out how to test for the case without `Set`...

Comment: @acl `FreeQ[Stack[], Set]` will get tripped up by something like `foo = g[f[x]]`.

Comment: @Brett maybe StackComplete could help then. But I admit I was already very much impressed with `Stack` as that was where I got (ahem) stuck.

Comment: @Brett I think I have a fix for that particular one which I will add, but as I can already see the next cases which break it. As I said I would not recommend to use this other than for learning purposes and probably for convenience when using own code...

Comment: Without knowing what pitfall you foresee, you probably want something tighter than `___` as the last element of the pattern.  Consider `a=f[b=g[f[x]]]`.  (I would say this is unlikely, but I saw a question using `Goto` yesterday...)

Comment: @BrettChampion Just an aside: MATLAB does not allow constructions like `a=f[b=g[f[x]]]` either...

Answer (score 7):

I can offer an alternative approach based on introspection and run-time code generation. It is not as elegant as one by @Albert, to be sure, but may still represent some interest. Here is the code (I made an assumption that your function is a symbol which has `DownValues`, but this can be generalized to other `...Values`:

```
ClearAll[withNArgOut];
SetAttributes[withNArgOut, HoldAll];
withNArgOut[code_] :=
  Hold[code] //.
   {
    HoldPattern[Set[vars_List, fcall : f_Symbol[___]]] /;
      FreeQ[Unevaluated[fcall], $nArgAout] && ! FreeQ[DownValues[f], $nArgAout] :>
            Set[vars, Block[{$nArgAout = Length[Unevaluated[vars]]}, fcall]],
    HoldPattern[Set[var_, fcall : _[___]]] /; 
       !MatchQ[Unevaluated[var], _List] &&
         Hold[var] =!= Hold[$nArgAout] && FreeQ[Unevaluated[fcall], $nArgAout] :>
            Set[{var}, fcall]
   };
```

I intentionally did not release the last `Hold`, so that we can see what is generated. Here is how you could use it:

```
ClearAll[f];
f[x_] := Table[x^i, {i, $nArgAout}]

In[14]:= {#,ReleaseHold@#}&@withNArgOut[Module[{a,b},b=1;a=f[x]]]
Out[14]= {Hold[Module[{a,b},b=1;{a}=Block[{$nArgAout=Length[Unevaluated[{a}]]},f[x]]]],{x}}

In[15]:= {#,ReleaseHold@#}&@withNArgOut[Module[{a,b,c}, c=1;{a,b}=f[x]]]
Out[15]= {Hold[Module[{a,b,c},c=1;
           {a,b}=Block[{$nArgAout=Length[Unevaluated[{a,b}]]},f[x]]]],{x,x^2}}

In[16]:= withNArgOut[Module[{a,b,c}, c=1;{a,b}=g[f[x]]]]
Out[16]= Hold[Module[{a,b,c},c=1;{a,b}=g[f[x]]]]
```

You can always add a call to `releaseHold` in the definition of `withNArgOut`. The usage is that you wrap the `withNArgOut` around the code where you want this to take effect, and the extra `Block[{$nArgAout= ...},...]` wrappers will be generated for that code (where appropriate), just prior to execution.